# How can I show uniqueness of a (constructed) topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a set, and $\Phi$ a set of subsets of $X$ such that:
>
> - $\varnothing, X \in \Phi$
> - If $\{ F_i: i\in I\}\subseteq \Phi$, then $\bigcap_{i} F_i \in \Phi$
> - If $F,G \in \Phi$ then $F\cup G \in \Phi$
>
> Show that there exists an **unique** topology $\tau$ on $X$, such that $\Phi$ is the set of all closed subsets of $(X,\tau)$.

I constructed the topology as follows:

$$\tau := \{ U = X\setminus A: A\in \Phi\}$$

And then I verified if this defines a topology. (checked the three rules)

But how can I show that this is unique? The fact that I proved this by construction doesn't make it unique does it?

Comment: You have to assume there are two such topologies and then show any open in one is contained in an open of the other.  That shows they are equal.

Comment: Something like this? Let $\tau, \tau'$ be two topologies where $\Phi$ is the set of all closed subsets. Let $U\in \tau$. Then $(\exists F\in \Phi)(U=X\setminus A)$. But if $A$ in $\Phi$ then  $X\setminus A\in \tau'$?

Comment: I find the language "the set containing all closed subsets" to be a bit confusing.  Does this just mean $\Phi$ is the set of all closed subsets?

Comment: yes, that seems like a better translation :)

Comment: Ok so in your argument do you mean $U=X\backslash F$?

Comment: Whoops, I meant ``$(\exists F\in \Phi)(U = X\setminus F)$. But if $F\in \Phi$ then $X\setminus F\in \tau'$'' Since $F$ is closed and $\tau'$ consists of all open subsets of $X$. (somehow the reasoning doesn't feel coherent... )

Comment: Now it looks good, you just have to make the final conclusion that therefore $X\backslash F$ is closed in $\tau'$ and therefore $U=X\backslash(X\backslash F)$ is open in $\tau'$

Comment: Okay, thanks. But in that reasoning I don't use the *'contained in an open of the other'*?

Comment: Well true, you showed $\tau$ is contained in $\tau'$, but now all you need to say is "by a symmetric argument $\tau'$ is contained in $\tau$.  Thus they are equal."

Comment: Final remark: You said: *...that therefore $X\setminus F$ is closed in $\tau'$ and therefore $U=X\setminus (X\setminus F)$ is open in $\tau'$.* But that's not what I stated (and I don't see why this would be the case). I state: $F\in \Phi$ means $F$ is closed in both $\tau$ and $\tau'$ ($F$ is closed in $\tau'$ since $\Phi$ is the set of all closed subsets). That would mean $X\setminus F$ to be **open** in $\tau'$?

Comment: Sorry you are right, minor details not a major conceptual mistake, I'd fix it but the edit period has expired.  I was just saying you didn't put in the final statement that $U$ is in $\tau'$ - I was just saying it could be written a bit cleaner that's all.  But it's the right idea.